# Where is a content provider stored in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

This might be a simple question, but I've had a hard time pinning down a direct answer.

I have created a content provider in its own separate package in a project using the Eclipse Android ADT. This package is included in the src of the overall project. When modifying AndroidManifest.xml I included this as a child of `<application`>:

```
 <provider android:name="JobProvider"
      android:authorities="dsndata.sds2Mobile.provider.JobProvider" />
```

The code that will be using the provider is in a separate package also in src

Where would be the best place to store the provider? In the same package as the source using it? Also, What are the correct values for android:name and android:authorities? I'm sure they vary depending on where the provider is stored.

Comment: Don't know the specific answer, but i was thinking that it might be better to manage Content Provider code as a seperate project, especially when it changes less frequently than the main project. I had lots of test data, so i wanted my apk for the main project to be small and not include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the provider wherever you like.  If you are writing a provider that stores data for your app (and only for your app, and only your app uses it) then it's cleanest to just be right in with the app code in its own package.  Typically, 'provider' is the package name.

As for the name and authority, see the [Manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html):

> **android:name** The name of the class
>   that implements the content provider,
>   a subclass of ContentProvider. This
>   should be a fully qualified class name
>   (such as,
>   "com.example.project.TransportationProvider").
>   However, as a shorthand, if the first
>   character of the name is a period, it
>   is appended to the package name
>   specified in the  element.
>   There is no default. The name must be
>   specified.
>
> **android:authorities** A list of one or
>   more URI authorities that identify
>   data under the purview of the content
>   provider. Multiple authorities are
>   listed by separating their names with
>   a semicolon. To avoid conflicts,
>   authority names should use a
>   Java-style naming convention (such as
>   com.example.provider.cartoonprovider).
>   Typically, it's the name of the
>   ContentProvider subclass. There is no
>   default. At least one authority must
>   be specified.

The content authority is a unique string that is used to map content:// uris (uri to data) to your class.  ContentResolver uses that mapping to identify how to serve a given request, which is identified with a URI, to the correct class (yours).  Hence the requirements for a unique string.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had worked out, but it's nice to get confirmation. :P

Answer (score 0):

you can Store your provider any place in your application.it depends upon whats your URI name provide in ContentProvider class.Always remember the URI name use in your Application must have unique authority and Path.

Android:name is your Content Provider class name with its package name
and Android:authorities is your URI content name where your Provider is available.
for more information you 
http://marakana.com/s/post/1375/android_content_provider_tutorial